# Retrieve data from JSON file and display images in a gallery

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm new to JQuery and any help would be much appreciated.

"Using $.getJSON function, retrieve the data in the items.json file provided and display the images in a gallery below. The gallery should display each image at roughly thumbnail size with its caption below it in a 3-column grid at desktop resolution."

I was able to get the the .json to output on the HTML page, now I was wondering how to get the actual images to show on the HTML page instead of the URL path of the images? This is what outputs to the HTML page currently:

- URL: images/image_1.jpg
- caption: Image 1 Caption
- URL: images/image_2.jpg
- caption: Image 2 Caption
- URL: images/image_3.jpg
- caption: Image 3 Caption
- URL: images/image_4.jpg
- caption: Image 4 Caption

***items.json***

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "url": "images/image_1.jpg",
        "caption": "Image 1 Caption"
    },
    {
        "url": "images/image_2.jpg.jpg",
        "caption": "Image 2 Caption"
    },
    {
        "url": "images/image_3.jpg.jpg",
        "caption": "Image 3 Caption"
    },
    {
        "url": "images/image_4.jpg.jpg",
        "caption": "Image 4 Caption"
    }
]
```

}

***scripts.js***

```
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $.getJSON('images.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i,f) {
            $("ul").append("<li>URL: "+f.url+"</li><li>Caption: "+f.caption+"</li><br />");

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: don't edit the question. clearly say whats your problem..

Comment: No error in console, I get an output. I would like the images to display as the output instead of the actual URL. Thanks.

Comment: Just use it Image tag instead if <li> tag - <img src="+f.url+" id="image"/>

Comment: Nothing shows, I get an error: Unexpected identifier. This is what I used: $("ul").append("<img src="+f.url+" id="image"/><li>Caption: "+f.caption+"</li><br />");

Comment: :(, I still can't get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('items.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,f) {
        $("ul").append("<li>URL: "+f.url+"</li><li>Caption: "+f.caption+"</li><br />");

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got all of the .json file to show on the HTML page. Now, how would you suggest that I display the actual images on the page instead of the names of the URL?

Comment: Yes, all in the same project folder. index.html and .json file are in the root directory and the images are in images folder. images/image_1.jpg, images/image_2.jpg, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for displaying img;

```
$.getJSON('js/ads.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function (i, f) {
                $("ul").append("<li>URL: " + f.url + "</li><li><img src="+f.url+" id=\"image\"/></li><br />");

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show just img use this(I used `div` with `id="images"`)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

            $.getJSON('items.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, f) {
                    $("#images").append("<img src=" + f.url + " >");

                });
            });
        });
```