# How to generate an image from a JSON file in django

Tags: python, json, django, image

I think I found this a while ago but right now I don't seem to find anything when googleing.

I have a model `Location`:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=true);
```

and a JSON file `mydata.json` that will load initial data:

```
[
  {
    "model": "locations.location",
    "fields": {
      "name": "Cafe"
    }
  }
]
```

and then when I do `python manage.py loaddata mydata` it loads the data. So now I am wondering if it's possible to load in a picture as well generated from the json. I don't mean just a link like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215744/retrieve-data-from-json-file-and-display-images-in-a-gallery) I mean a format that generates an image after. I think I read somewhere that it is possible I just can't find it anymore.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725579/images-in-django-fixtures

Comment: No, I clearly say >I don't mean just a link, I mean an image that gets generated

Comment: An image that gets generated from where? Presumably you have to supply the original image in some form - the answer in that question is suggesting you copy all your images into your media directory and then import that path into Django.

Comment: so when I start my app for the first time and I do `loaddata` I want this instance to be created with a picture. If I have to manually load something into the media directory, not quite the same. Maybe with a base64 code that gets encoded then