# get the .json to output on the HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, image

[Retrieve data from JSON file and display images in a gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25215744/7268257)

> I was able to get the the .json to output on the HTML page

@Jesuraja - How did you manage to do this. 
I am actully on the same state. I have JSON file having image local drive location  similar to yours I would like to know how you did the above step.
I just want an approach how should I proceed

Comment: Why would one edit this question instead of closing it?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
"items": [
    {
      "url": "images/image_1.jpg",
      "caption": "Image 1 Caption"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/image_2.jpg.jpg",
      "caption": "Image 2 Caption"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/image_3.jpg.jpg",
      "caption": "Image 3 Caption"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/image_4.jpg.jpg",
      "caption": "Image 4 Caption"
    }
  ]
};

function createGallery(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Image : "+array[i].url+"  Caption: "+array[i].caption));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}

// Add the contents of options[0] to #foo:
document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(createGallery(jsonObj.items));
```

```html
<div id="gallery"></div>
```